# Java and Makefiles: Is there any way to ensure if one class is dependent on another, to build that class first without being explicit?

Tags: java, makefile

Let's say I have 2 classes, Main.java and Car.java, Main.java depends on Car.java to have already be compiled when it's compiled, however, with using find to find src files and compile them one by one (so that way if one is unchanged it doesn't need to be recompiled) Main.java is always built first, but fails. This issue only gets worse with more complex projects. In C, this is alleviated by the use of header files, but java doesn't have such a feature.

What I have currently is explicitly telling make that Main.java depends on Car.java. While this works in small projects, this becomes less feasible with larger projects when each file depends on a handful of others, and each of those on others and so on.

Comment: Are you sure that this **is** a problem?  BTW why are you using `Makefiles` for java?

Comment: Positive. If I set the build rule to ignore errors, it will go on to build "Car.java" after failing to build Main.java, and  when I run it again, Main.java builds because "Car.class" now exists in the target directory. 
You can't import a java class if it doesn't exist yet..

Comment: why not `javac *.java` ?

Comment: In that scenario, I will have to rebuild every java class every time I build the project. So, with a project of 15 to 20 java source files, if I change just 1 of those source files, I have to build all 15 to 20 java source files, which can take quite some time.
If built one at a time, if I change one source file, only that one needs to be recompiled.

Comment: see https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/managing-projects-with/0596006101/ch09.html or use `Ant` `Maven` or `Gradle`

Comment: I guess you can't have everything with every language. I don't have the time to learn an alternative, so I will just settle for building them all at once, which, from the link you provided, shouldn't be as slow as I think it will be. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/managing-projects-with/0596006101/ch09.html
According to the above link, it's very difficult if not impossible to get the desired effects of C-like compiling source files separately in Java. However, java compiliers aren't as slow as C compilers when referencing and re-referencing the same class files, so this provides a performance boost when compiling all your java source files in a single invocation. This would seem to be the best solution to this issue.

Edit: This also greatly reduces the complexity of the makefile for larger projects, making them far more manageable.